# Trying to setup ReactNative project but getting hard time to install CocoaPods

Tags: ruby, xcode, react-native, cocoapods

Not able install Cocoapods when I tried with this `npx react-native init ProjectName` command and getting below error. (MacOS Mojave 10.14.4)

```
⠙ Installing CocoaPods dependencies (this may take a few minutes)/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems.rb:241:in `bin_path': can't find gem cocoapods (>= 0.a) (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
    from /usr/local/bin/pod:22:in `<main>'
✖ Installing CocoaPods dependencies (this may take a few minutes)
error Error: Failed to install CocoaPods dependencies for iOS project, which is required by this template.
Please try again manually: "cd ./AwesomeProject/ios && pod install".
CocoaPods documentation: https://cocoapods.org/
```

Please help to understand what's happening and how can we resolve this.

Comment: The error message gives you specific steps that you should follow. I assume you read the error message and followed the instructions it gave you, because it would be pretty silly to ask here first without trying that. What was the outcome?

Comment: Did you install cocoapods in your mac ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses but as it turns out my macOS ruby/gems not updated.. I updated all the required things and followed same steps now it's working fine.